# Cant get cells in table to scroll if over a certain px

Tags: html, css

I cant get the code here to add a scroll wheel in the cells when i the length of text gets bigger than a certain size.  I have a sample html and css that I am working from to get some help with:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: lightsteelblue;
}

form {
  background-color: purple;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid lightsteelblue;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin: 2px 6px 16px 0px;
}

button[type="submit"],
button.onclick {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: black;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #4C6E91;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover,
button.onclick:hover {
  background: steelblue;
}

select.option {
  text-align: center;
}

tr.comic {
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #000080;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" id="comic_list">
  <tr class="comic">
    <td>random text</td>
    <td>this is a long line of text that needs to be have a scroll attached to it for testing purposes to make sure that this area works. i know this last statement is a runon but its for testing. this space needs to be able to scroll. this text here is just garbage. This text here is to take up space to demenstrate a lage amount of text.Sorry if it makes no sense.</td>
    <td>random text</td>
    <td>random text</td>
    <td>random text</td>
    <td>random text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp3mdLgf/)**

I think this should be a simple question that has been answered before but I cant find an answer that works for me.

Thanks Zach